ValueError: The column label 'NPC' is not unique in Pandas DataFrame
I am working with a Pandas DataFrame that contains optimization results from HOMER software. I am encountering a ValueError indicating that the column label 'NPC' is not unique when I attempt to sort and select columns. Despite efforts to handle duplicate column names, the error persists.
thsi is the image that describes the error
What I Tried:

Removing Duplicate Columns:
I tried using the following code to remove duplicate column names:

homer_results.columns = homer_results.columns.str.strip() homer_results = homer_results.loc[:, ~homer_results.columns.duplicated()] 

Data Inspection:
I manually inspected the DataFrame and confirmed that there were duplicate column names.

Code to Sort and Select Columns:
The problematic code where the error occurs is:
optimal_solutions = homer_results[['NPC'] + target_columns].sort_values(by='NPC').head(10) 


I expected the DataFrame to sort by the 'NPC' column and to select the top 10 rows based on this sorted order. The DataFrame should then display the optimal solutions without any errors related to duplicate column labels.

Since you removed duplicates from dataframe columns, 'NPC' must be included in the target_columns list and as the result it gets selected twice. This would automatically remove duplicate columns from the selection:
optimal_solutions = homer_results[list(set(['NPC'] + target_columns))].sort_values(by='NPC').head(10)

